# ES bool and match when should be used?

Tags: elasticsearch

I got that bool has different options which influences scoring. In the other hand, match has other options like `lenient, minimum_should_match, operator`.

What is the real use of these two? Can we have one to satisfy all of these things?

Is my understanding wrong? When should I use bool and match?

Answer (score 0):

**[Bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)** is used to combine different queries. It provides below options
1. Must :

> The clause (query) must appear in matching documents and will contribute to the score.

It works like "AND" for different queries

2. Filter:

> The clause (query) must appear in matching documents. However unlike must the score of the query will be ignored

It works like "AND" but doesn't calculate score

3. Should :

> The clause (query) should appear in the matching document.

It works like "OR" for multiple queries

4. Must_not:

> The clause (query) must not appear in the matching documents. Clauses are executed in filter context meaning that scoring is ignored

**[Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)**
It is used for performing full text search

If you need a query to do full text search on a single field , you can use match query. If you need more than one query say a exact match on field(term query) and partial match on another field (match query). You will have to combine them using Bool clause.

Comment: So `bool` is something to provide boolean supports to `match` clauses. Does `operator` option of bool is not sufficient?

Comment: I think bool is a filter which should be used for exact value search and as you mentioned match is for full text search.

Comment: @Gibbs Bool is not a single query like match and doesn't have operator option. It is a compound query made up several other queries. Suppose if you are using a match and term query,then you need a way to combiem these whether they should be applied as OR or AND , bool is used in this scenario. To combine these

Comment: Thanks. I am kind of understood this. But I couldn't make this as answer - so upvoted it.

Comment: @Gibbs are you referring to bool or term query?

Comment: Thanks, I can improve the answer , what more info you need?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to bool query